# Calculate total time without vacations in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have a database table that represents `activities` and for each `activity`, how long it took.

It looks something like this :

```
activity_id  |  name  |  status  |  start_date     |    end_date
=================================================================
      1      | name1  |  WIP     | 2019-07-24 ...  | 2019-07-24 ...
```

`start_date` and `end_date` are timestamps. I use a view with a column `total_time` that is described like that:

```
date_part('day'::text, 
    COALESCE(sprint_activity.end_date::timestamp with time zone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
         - sprint_activity.start_date::timestamp with time zone
) + date_part('hour'::text, 
    COALESCE(sprint_activity.end_date::timestamp with time zone, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
         - sprint_activity.start_date::timestamp with time zone
) / 24::double precision AS total_time
```

I would like to create a table for vacation or half day vacations that looks like:

```
 date        |   work_percentage   
=================================================
2019-07-24   |       0.4
2019-07-23   |       0.7
```

And then, I would like to calculate `total_time` in a way that uses this vacations table such that:

1. If a date is not in the column it's considered to have `work_percentage==1`
2. For every date that is in the table, reduce the relative percentage from the `total_time` query.

So let's take an example:

1. Activity - "Write report" started at 11-July-2019 14:00 and ended at 15-July-2019 19:00 - so the time diff is 4 days and 5 hours.
2. The 13th and 14th were weekend so I'd like to have a column in the vacations table that holds `2019-07-13` with `work_percentage == 1` and the same for the 14th.
3. Deducting those vacations, the time diff would be 2 days and 5 hours as the 13th and 14th are not workdays.

Hope this example explains it better.

Comment: So, your date_part() calculation calculates what? The difference of the two timestamps? More precise: It is not clear why you split the operation into day and hour... Can you explain that more detailed please? Can you add a few more sample data sets including their timestamps? It is absolutely not clear to me what work_percentage is...

Comment: @S-Man - Let's say these are activities that employees in the company do. I want to create a report that shows how many days an activity took, without considering vacations. We also have half-days vacation (for example - we have half a day of a seminar - that's not a full day of work) so I want to count work percentage that day (If on Monday we only worked half-day, an employee who worked on an activity, only worked half a day on it).

Comment: @S-Man - I added an example, hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: Your calculation (with only day and hour) is wrong if the dates cross from one month to another. Why don't you work with the interval that you get from `COALESCE(sprint_activity.end_date, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - sprint_activity.start_date` and if those columns are already timestamps what do you expect from casting them again?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Ok, I will do that. But how do I take into account vacations or half-days?

Comment: So you need a table where all weekend days are listed? Or do you have the vacation table? How should a query know the values of your days?

Comment: @S-Man - Yes, we can assume I have this table (I really do have it)

Comment: @Avi please add some more sample data sets and the expected output. There are too many difficulties with such a query if the result is not clear. Nonetheless, I am sure, it's not difficult at all

Comment: @S-Man - I really appreciate you trying to help but I really don't know how to further elaborate the question. I have a list of tasks, with start date and end date, and I want to know how many days they actually took while considering vacations.

Comment: It would be great if you could add more than one data set and the expected result in your calculation. especially when we have to use other values than 1 day vacations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take this example and add some modifications based on your database

Just ddl statements to test script

```
create table activities (
    user_id int,
    activity_id int,
    name text,
    status text,
    start_date timestamp,
    end_date timestamp
);

create table vacations (
    user_id int,
    date date,
    work_percentage numeric
);

insert into activities
values
    (1, 1, 'name1', 'WIP', timestamp'2019-07-20 10:00:00', timestamp'2019-07-25 8:00:00'),
    (2, 2, 'name2', 'DONE', timestamp'2019-07-28 19:00:00', timestamp'2019-08-01 7:00:00'),
    (1, 3, 'name3', 'DONE', timestamp'2019-07-21 12:00:00', timestamp'2019-07-21 15:00:00'),
    (-1, 4, 'Write report', 'DONE', timestamp'2019-07-11 14:00:00', timestamp'2019-07-15 19:00:00');

insert into vacations
values
    (1, date'2019-07-21', 0.5),
    (1, date'2019-07-22', 0),
    (1, date'2019-07-23', 0.25),
    (2, date'2019-07-29', 0),
    (2, date'2019-07-30', 0),
    (-1, date'2019-07-13', 0),
    (-1, date'2019-07-14', 0);
```

sql script

```
with

daily_activity as (
    select
        *,
        date(
            generate_series(
                date(start_date),
                date(end_date),
                interval'1 day')
        ) as date_key
    from
        activities
),

raw_data as (
    select
        da.*,
        v.work_percentage,
        case
            when date(start_date) = date(end_date)
            then (end_date - start_date) * coalesce(work_percentage, 1)

            when date(start_date) = date_key
            then (date(start_date) + 1 - start_date) * coalesce(work_percentage, 1)

            when date(end_date) = date_key
            then (end_date - date(end_date)) * coalesce(work_percentage, 1)

            else interval'24 hours' * coalesce(work_percentage, 1)
        end as activity_coverage
    from
        daily_activity as da
        left join vacations as v on da.user_id = v.user_id
                                    and da.date_key = v.date
)

select
    user_id,
    activity_id,
    name,
    status,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    justify_interval(sum(activity_coverage)) as total_activity_time
from
    raw_data
group by
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: [Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2083523/avi), this solution worked for you?

Comment: Thanks Y.K! I still didn't test it as I'm on vacation. But I really need this question. If it works, I'll come back and let you know and accept it. Thanks a lot for your time investment!!!

Comment: You are welcome) It's interesting for me too, so I'll wait for news from you

Comment: I also thought about adding another table with working hours for each user

Comment: Hi, it didn't work exactly like what I needed but this gave me a great start to continue with.